# Multiple Upload Image GraphQL

Tags: laravel, vue.js, graphql

Good evening, Please help me with this line of code. I cannot display the array of image in the backend

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();
let objects = Object.values(queryVariables.image);

bodyFormData.set('operations', JSON.stringify({
  'query': savePostImage: `mutation savePostImage($image: [Upload!]) {
    savePostImage(image: $image) {
        error,
        message
    }
}`,
  'variables': queryVariables
}));

bodyFormData.set('operationName', null);

bodyFormData.set('map', JSON.stringify(queryVariables.image));
for (let i = 0; i<objects.length; i++){
   for (let i = 0; i<objects.length; i++){
        bodyFormData.append('file', objects[i]);
        bodyFormData.append('map', JSON.stringify({"file":[`variables.image.${[i]}`]}));
    }
}
```

and this is what happen if I uploaded it. Pleaser enlighten me. Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the payload tab show in your last image?

Comment: {"query":"mutation savePostImage($image: [Upload!]) {\n        savePostImage(image: $image) {\n            error,\n            message\n        }\n    }","variables":{"image":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{}}}}
operationName: 
null
map: 
{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{}}
0: 
(binary)
1: 
(binary)
2: 
(binary)

Comment: Please add it to the question, its unreadable like this ;)

Comment: already updated the question

Comment: Thanks for the update! What exactly are you dumping in the preview tab? seems like you are sending more data than just image? I dont see image in the payload. Are you sending php code? EDIT: My bad its graph ofc :)

Comment: its all images alone but it seems that i didnt pass any image file

Comment: I can see in your payload that there are 3 binaries added. But depending on what you are dumping, you mighe be accessing them the wrong way in the controller?

Comment: I already fixed some issue but I got only the last item array. can you please help me @Techno, already update the image above. thanks

Comment: Can you show what your `dd()` looked like in the first version?(code would be nice) It all depends on what you are trying to access